# Can I call .class on a generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if there is a way in Java to do something like

```
Class c = List<String>.class;
Class c2 = List<Date>.class;
```

I need something like this to create a map that stores the class name (with generic type) and the corresponding object which I can later lookup. For example,

```
Map<Class, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<Class, Object>();
dataMap.put(c, listOfStrings);
dataMap.put(c2, listOfDates);
```

Is this not possible because of type erasure during runtime ?

Answer (score 16):

You can't do it quite like this, but you *can* achieve your overall aim using the same approach as Guice does with [`TypeLiteral`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html). If you're using Guice already, I suggest you use that directly - otherwise, you might want to create your own similar class.

Essentially, the idea is that subclasses of a generic type which specify type arguments directly retain that information. So you write something like:

```
TypeLiteral literal = new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {};
```

Then you can use `literal.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` and get the type arguments from that. `TypeLiteral` itself doesn't need to have any interesting code (I don't know whether it *does* have anything in Guice, for other reasons).

Comment: @John:One small question for my benefit:Is it in generally a good option to introduce a dependency to a third party library to solve a single problem?I mean if it were cryptography for example I would understand that.But is there a limit when one should say, maybe I should "re-invent" it instead of adding extra 4MB in the footprint for example?

Comment: @user384706: No, I wasn't suggesting taking a dependency on Guice just for that. I explicitly said *if* you're using Guice already, you can use it - otherwise create your own type. If there were any significant code in `TypeLiteral` then taking a dependency might be more useful - but in this case it's the *idea* that's more interesting than the implementation.

Comment: Guava 12 (in a week or two) will have `TypeToken`, which has much the same role, albeit with a few more bells and whistles.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not possible. You can't even refer to `List<String>.class` in your code - it results in a compilation error. There is only one single class object for `List`, and it is called `List.class`.

> Is this not possible because of type erasure during runtime ?

Correct.

Btw this is a *generic* type, not an annotated type.

### Update

On second thought, you can have something fairly close to your Map above, by tweaking Josh Bloch's *typesafe heterogenous container* (published in *Effective Java* 2nd Ed., Item 29) a bit:

```
public class Lists {
    private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> lists =
            new HashMap<Class<?>, List<?>>();

    public <T> void putList(Class<T> type, List<T> list) {
        if (type == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
        lists.put(type, list);
    }

    public <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> type) {
        return (List<T>)lists.get(type);
    }
}
```

The cast in `getList` is unchecked, giving a warning, but I am afraid we can't avoid that. However, we know that the value stored for class `X` must be a `List<X>`, as this is guaranteed by the compiler. So I think the cast is safe (if you play by the rules, that is - i.e. never call `putList` with a plain nongeneric `Class` parameter), thus it can be suppressed using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

And you can use it like this:

```
Lists lists = new Lists();
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
...

lists.putList(Integer.class, integerList);
lists.putList(String.class, stringList);
List<Integer> storedList = lists.getList(Integer.class);

assertTrue(storedList == integerList);
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't wven know why I said annotated :-) Have fixed it.

Comment: @Rahul, please see my update for a potential solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as you are trying.
But you could [decorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) these lists and create a `MyListDates` and `MyListString` instead and store them in the hashmap