# How to access the .class from a class with a Generic?

Tags: java, generics

When it comes to classes without generics, i can access this .class attribute like this:

```
class Foo{
    Class<Foo> getMyClass(){
        return Foo.class;
    }
}
```

but how do i access this ".class" attribute if Foo has a generic? like this:

```
class Foo<T>{
    Class<Foo<T>> getMyClass(){
        return (Foo<T>).class //this doesnt work...
    }
}
```

i have tried to return `Foo.class`, but this is not going to work: `"cannot cast from Class<Foo> to Class<Foo<T>>"`.

How can i access `Foo<T>`'s class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I care that Java doesn't have reified generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927789/why-should-i-care-that-java-doesnt-have-reified-generics)

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate. The answers on that question are indicating how to create an instance from a generic type; my question is about accessing to the class of a template class. I would want to make an instance of `Foo<T>` via `Class<Foo<T>> x; x.newInstance()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I call .class on a generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257416/can-i-call-class-on-a-generic-type-in-java), [Java Generics Pass .class Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050626/java-generics-pass-class-reference), and [How to get parametrized Class instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585/how-to-get-parametrized-class-instance).

Comment: `Class<Foo<T>>` is meaningless due to type erasure and what the `Class` class does. Java is not C++. Generics are not templates. In your example above, `x.newInstance()` will return `Foo<?>` by definition since generics are a compile-time idea that does not exist at runtime, which is when reflection occurs.

Comment: FYI if you really want to use generics with reflection, you need to perform type casts. The compiler will likely mark them as unsafe, so you may need a `@SuppressWarnings()` annotation. I would double and triple check to make sure those casts really are safe. Warnings are there to help detect logic errors, but with reflection and generics, there really is no safe way out of it. Just be careful that you are not writing any "undocumented features."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always do this:

```
class Foo<T>{
    Class<Foo<T>> getMyClass(){
        return (Class<Foo<T>>)(Class<?>)Foo.class
    }
}
```

You will have unchecked cast warnings, because it indeed is unsafe -- as others have mentioned, the returned class object is not any more "`Foo<T>`'s class" as "`Foo<SomethingElse>`'s class".

Comment: This works, but you still get a warning... Is there a way of doing it without getting a warning?

Comment: @Martin: No, because there is not really any such thing as a `Class<Foo<T>>`. There is only one `Class` object for `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way, because of [type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101). This:

```
Foo<T>.class
```

... can not be obtained at runtime, it will always be the same type no matter what's the type of `T`. At runtime only this exists:

```
Foo.class
```

Comment: but, if Foo.class and `Foo<T>.class` are the same... why can't i do this?
`Class<Foo<T>> x = (Class<Foo<T>>) Foo.class`
this is going to give this error: `Cannot cast from Class<Foo> to Class<Foo<T>>`

Comment: You can't cast from `Foo.class` to `Class<Foo<T>>`, `Supremo<Integer>` is not a substitute for `Supremo`. It all boils down to type erasure, type information is lost at runtime rendering casts such as this invalid. Sorry, there's no way around it, it's a limitation inherent to Java.

Comment: thanks... it seems like i'll have to read more about type ereasure

Comment: @Bengalaa: You can never cast from `Foo<A>` to `Foo<B>` if `A` and `B` are different and not wildcards.