# Get a Class<Foo<T>> at runtime given generic type inputs

Tags: java, generics

I know there are a lot of questions about similar issues already, but I haven't found one to directly address this one.

Here is the skeleton of the code I'm trying to implement:

```
class MyObj<T> {
    // Internals are unimportant ...
}

private <T> void foo(T arg) {
    Class<MyObj<T>> clazz = // What do I write here?

    // Here is one thing that works, but is quite ugly:
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    clazz = (Class<MyObj<T>>)(new MyObj<T>().getClass())

    // ...

    // Later, clazz is passed to a constructor of some other class
    OtherClass<MyObj<T>> foo = new OtherClass<>(clazz);
}
```

**Question 1:** Does anyone have a better suggestion of how to populate `clazz` ? Ideally, it would avoid calling `new`.

**Question 2:** Given the ugly (but working) code above, are there any situations where it could break? I don't like to `@SuppressWarnings`, and worry about problems I might be hiding.

Comment: Related: [How to access the .class from a class with a Generic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634631/how-to-access-the-class-from-a-class-with-a-generic)

Comment: Due to erasure, `Class<MyObj<T>>` will just be bound to any `Object`.  It may be better to use `Class<?>` instead; this way, you could also just pull the class information from `arg` via `arg.getClass()`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `clazz`?

Comment: @TedHopp clazz, in my case, is passed on to yet another layer of generics. It will be passed to another class constructor, which uses that Class<T> internally to instantiate, etc. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Makoto: If I understand correctly, I can't use `arg.getClass()` since that will give me a `Class<T>`, whereas I want a `Class<MyObj<T>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid instantiating, you can write:

```
Class<MyObj<T>> clazz = (Class) MyObj.class;
```

Due to erasure, there exists a single `Class` instance for `MyObj`, regardless of whatever type parameters it might have, so although this is ugly, it is safe.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I also saw the following variant at another question linked in comments: `clazz = (Class<MyObj<T>>)(Class<?>)MyObj.class`. Funny how that double-cast is needed in that case...

Comment: @jwd: Imagine that you want to cast from `Integer` to `String`. They are incompatible types, so you couldn't write `String s = (String) i`: the compiler can tell that that's not O.K. You'd have to upcast to `Object` and *then* downcast to `String`: `String s = (String) (Object) i`. (And then you'd get a `ClassCastException`, of course.) As far as the type system is concerned, this is the same thing; you need to upcast your `Class<MyObj>` to a `Class` or a `Class<?>` in order to trick the compiler into letting you downcast to `Class<MyObj<T>>`. *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* The reason that my version requires only a single explicit cast -- an upcast to `Class`, with no downcast to `Class<MyObj<T>>` -- is that raw types have special treatment in Java, and allow you to implicitly (and unsafely) convert to any corresponding parameterized type.